# A strange issue of CUDA compiling

Tags: cmake, compilation, cuda

The project is built by CMake and compiled by Visual Studio 2015. 
And the cuda code is compiled into .lib file using the CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY command.

The code shows as below:

```
//kernel.h
#pragma once
void run_kernel();

//kernel.cu
#include "kernel.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel1()
{
    printf("kernel1\n");
}
__global__ void kernel2()
{
    printf("kernel2\n");
}

void run_kernel()
{
    kernel1 <<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The above code is expected to output the string **kernel1** in the CMD window, but it outputs the **kernel2** instead.

This weird problem only occurs in my current solution and only happens in the release mode.
I tried many things, including rebuilding the project, removing the Cmake cache, and organizing the cuda code as a separate project of the solution. But it keeps appearing.

In addition, I also did some experiments and found that the problem may be that the name of the function cannot be distinguished. Functions that are defined later may **override** those defined first, as long as their **parameter lists are the same**.

The entire solution includes a large number of codes and dependencies so it can't be shared effectively. I am sorry this problem is hard to reproduce for you, but I have been stuck in this problem for several days. I hope that you can give me any clue about this issue, and I am very grateful to everyone who sees or writes something under this question. If I progress a bit, I will also include it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

It turns out that this project uses the compiler optimization option: [/GL(Whole Program Optimization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=vs-2015) and /LTCG.
I removed these options and everything is correct.